# how to prevent page refresh when removing a row from a table with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a web page with a table and a "remove row" link in each row of the table.

Problem is, when I click to delete a row, the browser does a page refresh.  How do I prevent his from happening?

Here's a complete functioning HTML page.  Try it, scroll down to the rows, click a link causes the scrollbar to jump back up to the top:

NOTE: I'm using Firefox 11.

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript">

function deleteRow(rowID) {
  try {
    var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
    var iRowIndex = 0;
    while (iRowIndex < table.rows.length) {
      var row = table.rows[iRowIndex];
      if (row.id == rowID) {
        table.deleteRow(iRowIndex);
      } else {
        iRowIndex++;
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }
}

</SCRIPT>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>


<table id="mytable">
  <tr id="foo" >
    <td>FOO</td>
    <td>
       <a href="#" onclick="deleteRow('foo')">remove</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="bar" >
    <td>BAR</td>
    <td>
       <a onclick="deleteRow('bar')">remove</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In this example, it doesn't refresh: http://jsfiddle.net/Rc8sQ/

Comment: Thanks for that -- never seen jsfiddle before -- but when I click the 'remove' link there, it doesn't disappear at all.  Am I using jsfiddle incorrectly?

Comment: you could give each row its own tbody with unique id and set that tbody to display:none. That is what I use for reliable cross browser functionality.

Comment: I updated my question with a functioning HTML that demonstrates my problem.  Thanks!  I'm using Firefox 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your page is refreshing is because of the `href="#"` in your anchor tag. Removing that should make your example work.

Removing the `href="#"` snippet will also removing the selector cursor on hover of the anchor element. If you wish to maintain that styling, it's easy to fix with a little css.

```
.myAnchor:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I tried removing the href, but I still have the refresh/scrollbar jump issue.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I copy/pasted your example code into jsfiddle and I didn't have any issues. Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rd63a/

Comment: Thanks, yes it seems to work in jsfiddle, but not when I copy-paste that code into a jstest1.html file and open it with firefox 11 or IE 8.  Any idea why not?

Comment: Ah!  No, it is working!  I had to click "refresh", firefox didn't load the new fixed version.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Cool it's working. Last thing I'd like to point out is the inline event registration model you're using and why it might not be the best way to use. Here is the link: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html

Answer (score 0):

why do you use the href? Don't you just need to catch the onclick event?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you used a `<a>` link and gave it the `href="#"` attribute, so it'll link (so refresh) to the page.

You can either remove the `href="#"` attribute, or prevent the default action of the  link in your function (see the code below), or use another type of control, like button. You can always change the look-and-feel with CSS.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function displayResult(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(0);
         }
      </script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <table id="myTable" border="1">
         <tr>
            <td>cell 1</td>
            <td>cell 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>cell 3</td>
            <td>cell 4</td>
         </tr>
      </table>

      <a href="#" onclick="displayResult(event)">Delete first row</a>
   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Removing the `href="#"` didn't help.  I also tried `onclick="deleteRow(event, '<%=rowId %>')"` and `function deleteRow(event, rowId) { e.preventDefault(); ...` -- but it no longer deletes the row -- maybe I'm passing the `event` in incorrectly?